# value is not storing in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I started to learn php but stuck in somewhere. Below is my php code to show what i did. I made `add to cart` part with `storing IP address and product id` but still the value is not saving database. How to check what's wrong in code? I also checked it using e`cho mysqli_error($db)` but not showing.

below is code :

```
<?php 

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");


function getIp() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}


function cart(){

    if (isset($_GET['add_cart'])) {

        global $db;

        $ip = getIp();
        $pro_id = $_GET['add_cart'];
        $check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id='$pro_id'";

        $run_check = mysqli_query($db, $check_pro);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0) {
            echo "";
        } else {
            $insert_pro = "insert into cart (p_id,ip_add) values ('$pro_id','$ip')";

            $run_pro = mysqli_query($db , $insert_pro);
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Even adding image of database table.

[image]

Comment: Where have you put mysqli_error?

Comment: `p_id` is auto incremented so not use in insert query!!Because it is already in your table!!

Comment: please print query in browser and paste that query in phpmyadmin...and see what error occured.

Comment: @zac after if statement i put this in else statement

Comment: @Saty so now in this case what to do?

Comment: Just use `$insert_pro = "insert into cart (ip_add) values ('$ip')";
` You will get new p_id for that ip

Comment: @SagarKodte Maybe the problem is in the if statement, you have a echo ""

Comment: actually i am lerning through some tutorial there is working here is not working

Comment: @Saty `p_id` is not auto incremented, it's primary key.

Comment: Side note: if that tutorial really suggests embedding raw GET variables into SQL I suggest you find another reference. That practice make code harder to write and will get your site hacked.

Comment: cart function is not called

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this is not proper technique??

Comment: cart functiom is called @Zac <?php cart(); ?> like this in index.php

Comment: @MindaugasM. my bad luck. not worked :(

Comment: What is the internet address you are trying to load? Can you put it there? @SagarKodte

Comment: i doing it on localhost

Comment: @SagarKodte my mistake, I didn't noticed that you've already added echo in function... Did you pass any integer number to `$_GET['add_cart']`?

Comment: @SagarKodte You can google for "SQL Injection" and check our classic question [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @MindaugasM. yes i passed integer number of pro_id

Comment: Can you insert the full address you put? http://localhost/index.php?add_cart=18 .. Something like it?

Comment: yes this is shwoing after click on button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the status of almost all `mysqli_` api calls, see the 2 checks I have added

```
function cart(){

    if (isset($_GET['add_cart'])) {

        global $db;

        $ip = getIp();
        $pro_id = $_GET['add_cart'];
        $check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id='$pro_id'";

        $run_check = mysqli_query($db, $check_pro);

        // test query worked and report error if it failed
        if ($run_check === false) {
            echo mysqli_error($db);
            exit;
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0) {
            echo "";
        } else {
            $insert_pro = "insert into cart 
                                  (p_id,ip_add) 
                           values ('$pro_id','$ip')";

            $run_pro = mysqli_query($db , $insert_pro);

            // test query worked and report error if it failed
            if ($run_pro === false) {
                echo mysqli_error($db);
                exit;
            }

            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

This will likely show you your error.

It is likely you have already INSERTED a row with the key you are using

> By the way:
>   Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Field 'qty' doesn't have a default value is showing. I saw qty field in tutroial there is no default value.but working.

Comment: i changed DEFAULT value of qty to null it works but it's proper to go ahead?

Comment: I would go for a default of Zero as it will make more sence later to have a 0 qty than a null qty